# How to combine the values of two matrices having different size in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array

I have A = (n,m) array and B = (n,p,q) array. For each n,p,q, I want to impose that when one of the element of B has a value >0 then the corresponding value of A (for the same n) is 0. Then, I would like to obtain q versions of A or a A of size (n,m,q). Thanks

Comment: can you give a short example of your data and what you want it to look like?

Comment: your description of the problem is not complete, and please, give us a short example

Comment: The question is unclear. For example corresponding value of A is unclear or for each n,p,q one of the element of B (does not seem to depend on n,p or q. Also how should q versions of A differ.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want?

```
result = bsxfun(@times, A, B<=0);
```

For example,

```
A =
     2     2     2     2
     3     3     3     1
     3     2     3     3

B(:,:,1) =
   -0.3906   -1.2784    0.3662   -1.2602
    0.7467   -0.3885    0.3249    2.0529
   -0.2782   -0.8268   -0.4256    0.7897
B(:,:,2) =
    0.2148   -0.9502   -0.4125    0.1795
    1.2660    0.4453    0.0328   -1.6019
    0.2740   -0.6132    0.7554    1.4524
```

give

```
result(:,:,1) =
     2     2     0     2
     0     3     0     0
     3     2     3     0

result(:,:,2) =
     0     2     2     0
     0     0     0     1
     0     2     0     0
```

Comment: I was thinking about `B<=0` rather than `B>0` but am not sure which is correct.